# Get table depending on selected value from dropdownlist MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a model component, subcomponent and evaluation:

```
public class Evaluation
    {
        public virtual int EvaluationId { get; set; }

        public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Component Component { get; set; }

        public virtual int UserCourseId { get; set; }
        public virtual UserCourse User { get; set; }

        public virtual int Grade { get; set; }
    }

 public class Component
    {
        public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }

        public virtual string Type { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Course Course { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Subcomponent> Subcomponents { get; set; }

}

public class Subcomponent
    {
        public virtual int SubcomponentId { get; set; }
        public virtual int ComponentId { get; set; }

        public virtual string TypeSub { get; set; }
        public virtual string NameSub { get; set; }

        public virtual int ParentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Subcomponent Parent { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Subcomponent> Childs { get; set; }

        public virtual Component Component { get; set; }

}
```

And as you can see, a component have a list of subcomponents and a subcomponent can have unlimited subcomponents.
I need to give grades to a component, but if that component have a subcomponent the grade must be given to that subcomponent,
and so on. The last subcomponent is the one to be able to give a grade.
My idea was to select a component and on selecting the component in the dropdownlist a table appears with the subcomponents.
I have this view:

```
@model SGP.Models.Evaluation
...
<div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ComponentId, "Component")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ComponentId", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ComponentId)
        </div>


        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Grade)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Grade)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Grade)
        </div>
```

I can select the components but i don't know how to get the subcomponents in the way i need. Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: First you should trash the subcomponent class because the are pretty much the same thing as component.  Just make the list a list of components and anything such as parent up to the compenent class.  No need to have both.  Also no need for a parentID because the component will have a reference to it's parent already which can be accessed easily enough.  Also, what is the difference between SubcomponentId and ComponentId?  I know this really doesn't help, but if you get rid off all the redundancies, your solution might be easier to see.

Comment: Also, how many direct kids will a component have, not including grandchildren?

Comment: @JSON The subcomponents and components have different variables, but there are a lot of them so i reduced to two just for this case. The subcomponentId and componentId are the ids for each model. A component can have infinite subcomponents, and subcomponents can have infinite subsubcomponents and so on.

Comment: What are the different values between subcomponent and component?  I fail to see any that are of big relevance. From what I see you are trying to make a tree like structure. You are using component like a root node, however, subcomponent can do that just fine.  The only difference is your parent would then be null, which is expected when working with tree like data structures

Comment: When traversing through tree like data structures recursion is key.  I would suggest looking into Trees.  Something like this might be helpful http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/19b1bd/binarysearchtreewalkstraversal-implementation-using-C-Sharp/  The only difference is instead of only 2 child nodes per node, you have many.  However, the traversal method is the same